# Can I open an MAC Office 2011 Excel application and create docs using COM (Component Object Model)?

Tags: macos, com, ms-office

On windows I can write an an application to open excel and manipulate a document.

```
' Create new Application.
Dim excel As Application = New Application  
' Open Excel spreadsheet.
Dim w As Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\file.xls")
```

This can be done in a variety of languages, however is it possible to do the same with Mac Office 2011 with Objective-C or other?

This article from 2004 suggested that there is some support, and in the 2011 application I can embed objects in PPT form excel for example. Highlighting that registry is missing, however, if know location of library it would be possible.

http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2004/04/16/com_osx.html?page=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use AppleScript to control Excel on the Mac.

For Example

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    make new workbook
end tell
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/113891